# XML <message> not bringing through data

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, feed

I have an xml feed that brings through job vacancy data to a website I'm developing.

If there are no jobs the XML feed will state

```
<message>No Vacancies were found matching your search criteria.</message>
```

I can get the 'No vacancies...' message to appear but it will only show the first result of the XML (i know there should be more than one job result).

This is how the XML outputs

```
    <nhs_search>

  <status>
    <number_of_jobs_found>2</number_of_jobs_found>
    <message></message>
  </status>

  <vacancy_details>
    <id>913159135</id>
    <job_reference>489-CCG-03</job_reference>
    <job_title>Clinical Project Manager</job_title>
    <job_description>Clinical Commissioning Groups (CCGs) have a shared management team. . These posts will complement the current team of clinical project managers that we already have. The posts are...</job_description>
    <job_type>Fixed Term Temporary</job_type>
    <job_specialty></job_specialty>
    <job_salary>&#163;30,764 to &#163;40,558 pa</job_salary>
    <job_location>England</job_location>
    <job_closedate>12/08/2013</job_closedate>
    <job_postdate>29/07/2013</job_postdate>
    <job_url>http://www.jobs.nhs.uk/cgi-bin/vacdetails.cgi?selection=567657567</job_url>
  </vacancy_details>

  <vacancy_details>
    <id>913155230</id>
    <job_reference>489-CCG-02</job_reference>
    <job_title>Designated Nurse for Children in Care</job_title>
    <job_description>Are you experienced in working with looked after children? If you are we would be interested to hear from you. An exciting opportunity has arisen for an experienced nurse to join the Clinical Commissioning Group in the role of Designated Nurse for Children in Care. This new post will also support the Designated Nurse for Safeguarding Children. In line with...</job_description>
    <job_type>Permanent</job_type>
    <job_specialty>Nursing</job_specialty>
    <job_salary>&#163;39,239 to &#163;47,088 pa</job_salary>
    <job_location>England</job_location>
    <job_closedate>30/07/2013</job_closedate>
    <job_postdate>23/07/2013</job_postdate>
    <job_url>http://www.jobs.nhs.uk/cgi-bin/vacdetails.cgi?selection=54678965</job_url>
  </vacancy_details>

</nhs_search>
```

XPath is currently set to

```
XPath="nhs_search"
```

and the page code is

```
<ItemTemplate> 

                <tr>                    
                    <td class="vacs"><asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# XPath("vacancy_details/job_url") %>' Text='<%# XPath("vacancy_details/job_title") %>' Target="_blank" runat="server" ID="Hyperlink2" />
                    <br /><%# XPath("vacancy_details/job_specialty")%></td> 
                    <td class="vacs"><%# XPath("vacancy_details/job_salary")%></td>
                    <td class="vacs"><%# XPath("vacancy_details/job_closedate")%></td>
                 </tr>
                 <td class="vacs"><%# XPath("status/message")%></td>
                 <tr>

                 </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is this code will only bring the top result through? How can i get it to bring through all search results?

Comment: Where did you place the `message` code? Exactly what output are you seeing in the case that there are no jobs?

Comment: I've had a further look and the problem is to do with the XPath. I'll update the question above